# How do I remove specific Jenkins User permissions form a User using Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, permissions

I am able to **add** a specific [Permission](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/security/Permission.html) to a [User](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/class-use/User.html) using the following common script:

```
import hudson.model.*
import Jenkins.*
import hudson.security.Permission
import hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy

String userId = "my_user"
List<String> userPermissionList = [hudson.model.Item.CONFIGURE]

Hudson instance = Jenkins.get()
GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy authStrategy = Jenkins.instance.getAuthorizationStrategy()

// Adding each permission from list
userPermissionList.each { permission ->
    authStrategy.add(permission, userId)
    instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(authStrategy)
}

instance.save()
```

However, I looked everywhere to find how to remove a specific permission from a user. Looking at [GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/matrix-auth/hudson/security/GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy.html), there is a `add()` method, however no `remove()` of any sort.

Is this even possible??? *(it has to be)*

Or do I have add the difference to the user? As in, clear the user of all permissions and add back all but the ones I want to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

The Permission class has an attribute called `enabled` with associated getters and setters.  You can add a permission by setting `permission.enabled = true` and to remove the permission you should explicitly set `permission.enabled = false`

> The default value for `permission.enabled` may be different depending on what version of Jenkins you are running.  It is best to explicitly set this value either way

```
import hudson.model.*
import Jenkins.*
import hudson.security.Permission
import hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy

def userId = "gnocras"
def userPermissionList = [hudson.model.Item.CONFIGURE]

Hudson instance = Jenkins.get()
GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy authStrategy = Jenkins.instance.getAuthorizationStrategy()

// Removing each permission from list
userPermissionList.each { permission ->
    permission.enabled = false
    authStrategy.add(permission, userId)
    instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(authStrategy)
}

instance.save()
```

> This intended to be ran in the Jenkin's **Script Console**

Before running the above script the user had the following permission

[image: with permission]

And after running this script the user had the following permission

[image: without permission]

If I rerun the script with `permission.enabled = true` the user has the following permission

[image: with permission]

Comment: You are correct. Works.  Seems like I had a lack of understanding how exactly this works but makes sense now.  

However, for me at least it seems to default to `true`, because I was able to add the permission without specifying the `enabled` property.

In any case, thank you very much!

Comment: @cat_nip_coffee glad it works.  Odd, they must have switched the default value from false to true between or different versions.  I have updated my answer accordingly in case others stumble upon the question

Answer (score 2):

According to the document.

https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/security/Permission.html#enabled

enabled : Whether this permission is available for use

So Enable=false will remove the role from setting, means the whole column will disappear.

and this document works for me,

**getGrantedPermissionEntries()**:
Returns a live modifiable map of permissions.

**Since:3.0**
https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/matrix-auth/org/jenkinsci/plugins/matrixauth/AuthorizationContainer.html#getGrantedPermissionEntries--

```
import hudson.security.*
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.matrixauth.PermissionEntry
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.matrixauth.AuthorizationType
def user = new PermissionEntry(AuthorizationType.USER, 'woody.wei')
println user
def strategy = Jenkins.instance.authorizationStrategy
entryMap = strategy.getGrantedPermissionEntries()
entryMap.keySet().each{
    entryMap[it] -= user
}
```

getGrantedPermissionEntries returns a map, each permission holds it's permission entries, looks like this.

> `{Permission[class hudson.model.View,Delete]=[PermissionEntry{type=GROUP, sid='authenticated'}], Permission[class hudson.model.Computer,Connect]=[PermissionEntry{type=GROUP, sid='authenticated'}], Permission[class hudson.model.Run,Delete]=[PermissionEntry{type=GROUP, sid='authenticated'}], Permission[class hudson.model.Computer,Create]=[PermissionEntry{type=GROUP, sid='authenticated'}], Permission[class com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider,ManageDomains]=[PermissionEntry{type=USER, sid='woody.wei'}, PermissionEntry{type=GROUP, sid='authenticated'}]}`

To move a specific permission, construct a permission like this, then remove the entry in it.

```
Permission.fromId('hudson.model.Item.Cancel')
```